# Using EntityUtils in Android causes the thread to crash

Tags: android

I'm currently trying to send a post to a php script, which seems to work fine. However, when I try and extract the string from the HttpEntity it causes the thread to crash. I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
String postURL = "<hidden/not relevant>";
HttpPost categoryPost = new HttpPost(postURL);
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userID", userID));
UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
categoryPost.setEntity(ent);
responsePOST = client.execute(categoryPost);
HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();

if (resEntity != null) {
    // TODO Fix this line!!!
    //categoryTest = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

    // TODO Then uncomment this line.
    //playedCategories = categoryTest.split(",");

    // This strangely works, but the first use(above) of EntityUtils does not.
    Log.i("RESPONSE", EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
}
```

The Log prints the correct string from resEntity out to LogCat, but the line  above it is causing the crash.

Following Errors:
when 
`categoryTest = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);` 
is uncommented I get the following error on the VD screen: "process * has stopped unexpectedly" and the following error in LogCat:

```
03-13 23:48:13.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(220): Uncaught handler: thread Thread-8 exiting due to uncaught exception
03-13 23:48:13.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(220): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed
03-13 23:48:13.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(220):     at org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity.getContent(BasicHttpEntity.java:84)
03-13 23:48:13.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(220):     at org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity.getContent(BasicManagedEntity.java:100)
03-13 23:48:13.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(220):     at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:112)
03-13 23:48:13.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(220):     at org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(EntityUtils.java:146)
03-13 23:48:13.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(220):     at android.triviarea.data.User.requestAvailableCategories(User.java:112)
03-13 23:48:13.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(220):     at android.triviarea.main.MainScreen$1$1.run(MainScreen.java:63)
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to make sense. What happens with the first line uncommented?

Comment: @Matthew Willis 
I updated my post with the specific line and Error output. Thanks for any help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not call `EntityUtils.toString(entity)` twice if your [entity is not repeatable](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContent%28%29).